# What FIFA year is being played in this video?

Tags: game-identification

In [this video](https://youtu.be/5LZ_G8jRGHg), Dude Perfect is playing *FIFA* with dunk tanks.  The gameplay looks a lot different from *FIFA 21*, and it makes me curious:  What year of *FIFA* are they playing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It appears to be FIFA19 based off of the scrolling "ads" as seen in this screenshot from the video (top left):

[image]